# Can't able to truncating tables when seeding in laravel 7

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-7

I am facing an issue with laravel 7 while truncating table, even I have used FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS enable and disable still is return this type of error "Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint".

**Method**

```
DB::statement("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;");

Artisan::call('db:seed', ["--database" => 'DBNAME', '--force' => true, "--class" => 'StatusTableSeeder']);

DB::statement("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;");
```

**Seeder File**  StatusTableSeeder.php

```
public function run()
{
    \DB::table('statuses')->truncate();
    \DB::table('statuses')->insert(array (
            0 => 
            array (
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'Current',
                'type' => 'current',
            ),
            1 => 
            array (
                'id' => 2,
                'name' => 'Resolved',
                'type' => 'resolved',
            ),
       ));
}
```

I have updated laravel version 6 to 7, this syntax works fine in laravel 6 but when I update it to laravel 7 then after it is working. If anyone Have idea about it what's the actual issues

Comment: may be other table will having foreign key from truncate table.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra Yes, but I have FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0  it was working fine in laravel 6 this issue only appears in laravel 7

Comment: Read Reference Manual and study how `TRUNCATE` statement is **really** performed. You'll understand that intermediate DB state is inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class StatusTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        DB::table('statuses')->truncate();
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();

        // and the rest of your code...
    }
}
```